# Cannot write into /sys/power/mem_sleep in Fedora 36

Tags: fedora, power-management, suspend, system-calls, sleep

Since I failed to find a way to tell `systemctl` to go to sleep in a one-time specified mode (see [previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/719830/on-the-fly-switch-between-deep-and-idle-sleep)), I decided to write some script to change whether the system goes to sleep in shallow or deep mode by writing directly into `/sys/power/mem_sleep`.

Available values on my system are `s2idle` and `deep` (default).

However, though I did that before, I cannot do it anymore: `echo "[s2idle] deep" | sudo tee /sys/power/mem_sleep` returns `tee: /sys/power/mem_sleep: write error: Invalid argument` and manual edit via `vim` as root I also cannot save.
I think I set the default kernel sleep mode to be `deep`... could that be the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think if you `cat /sys/power/mem_sleep`, you'll see a list, with the one selected in brackets:

```
$ cat /sys/power/mem_sleep
s2idle [deep]
```

If you want to *change* the selection, write the name of the one you want, not the entire line:

```
$ echo s2idle | sudo tee /sys/power/mem_sleep
$ cat /sys/power/mem_sleep
[s2idle] deep
```

If your desired state does appear in this list, check your BIOS or UEFI setup for suspend-related settings.

Comment: damn, that was simple, I should have thought of it from the behavior of ``/sys/power/state``, thanks for your help!

Comment: It's actually not that simple. Things like `sudo echo "s2idle" > /sys/power/mem_sleep`, or `sudo echo "s2idle" >> /sys/power/mem_sleep`, don't work due to permissions issues since apparently the `echo` command gets `sudo` applied, but not the writing part to the file. So, the `sudo tee` technique, oddly enough, is required.

Comment: @AndyDalton, nobody suggested it here. But I was stuck on that and landed here after a google search. I suspect others land here from similar Google searches, so I just figured I'd point it out.